# Do POST requests carry PHP session values accross servers?

Tags: php, session, post, curl

If I'm using PHP to perform a cURL POST to a remote server running code containing `session_start()`, is it possible to access session variables set on the local machine on the remote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've got PHP trans_sid option turned on (BAD idea), POST has nothing to do with session values. That's mediated through a standard cookie.

Cookies are bound by same-domain security settings - they CAN be shared between hosts in the same domain (e.g. foo.example.com and bar.example.com), but an Amazon cookie cannot be shared with Yahoo.

Comment: not entirely true- `session.use_trans_sid` being off doesn't prohibit php from using a session id passed in the request via a post field. `session.use_only_cookies` is the closest setting for that. I'm sure you knew that, but most readers of your post probably don't.

Comment: You can definitely manually insert the session ID into query strings, hidden form fields, blah blah blah, but it's a major security hole to do so, and with trans_sid off, PHP will not pick up that session ID automatically.

Comment: it *will* resume a session from an id in post/get unless you enable `session.use_only_cookies`, and its been this way for years. try it. http://pastebin.com/xhYa33Kp

Answer (score 0):

No they do not. Even sending a session cookie, which you can do with cURL POST, will reference a session which exists only on the requesting server.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The session variables are server-specific.  They only cross to another server if the session ID were to be set correctly, and if they were using a shared session data-store, such as memcached.